# How to embed Xamarin.Forms in native Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to embed a XAML page created with `Xamarin.Forms` in my native `Xamarin.Mac` application.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to embed into a Xamarin.Mac project or a ObjC/Swift native project?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this guide](https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-xamarin-native/) for embedding XAML in native UI. The approach is very similar to iOS, there is an analogous `CreateViewController` extension method [available in Xamarin.Mac](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/bd31e1e9fc8b2f9ad94cc99e0c7ab058174821f3/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS/Extensions/PageExtensions.cs):

```
nativeViewController = new MyPage().CreateViewController();
_navigation.PushViewController(nativeViewController, true);
```

Comment: Thank you Martin! What is the declared type of  **_navigation**? The only corresponding type I find is UINavigationController which is available only on iOS.
Thanks